# how to elegantly pass URI parameters in key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have a function

```
personsPaginated(
    params: { searchString?: string; pageNumber?: number; perPage?: number; office?: string, notary?: boolean, cpr?: boolean, hrdept?: number, legaldept?: number, committee?: number } = {
      pageNumber: 1,
      perPage: 10,
      office: null, 
      notary: null,
      hrdept: null,
      committee: null
    }
  )
```

When I call this function, I can include/exclude any of the values, including any as a key/value pair.

However, since some of these pairs are variables that cannot be null, I need to find a way to exclude the pair if the value is such it should not be included. example: hrdept could be 0 which means include all.

I want to find a way to call the params without writing a massing string of if/else statements.

```
if ( hrdept > 0 ) { 
  personsPaginated( searchString, pageNumber, perPage, office, notary, hrdept, committee)
}
else {
  personsPaginated( searchString, pageNumber, perPage, office, notary, committee)
}
```

if/else statements would be lengthy and tedious. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Why your function receives so many parameters? Can't it be just an object?

Comment: This is a database in which the application has a variety of ways of filtering the data.  This function returns the data to be displayed, filters in one of the variety of ways. 

There is a search box (which returns a searchString), office dropdown to select which office, then other functions which filter the data. 

If I knew how to pass an object, that might work.  I can get it to work with a string of if/else statements, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Comment: If all the params are opcional I wonder how the compiler would recognize what you want to ommit or not in the arguments. For example: personsPaginated(1,2,3) is supposed to be what?

Comment: They're key/value pairs.  If I pass stringSearch : Larry, personPaginated will know to filter names that contains Larry.  If I pass notary: true, personPaginated knows to filter for all records where notary is true.  It will still do this is there is no stringSearch, because it processes by the key/value pair.

Comment: Ummmm. I can't see a way to do what you want without if else. You must check some conditions before assigning the params, so you may want to use switch case instead?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this without nesting if/else statements.

- thanks to [testing_22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12096922/testing-22) for the idea

```
const paramString = {searchString,pageNumber,perPage,office,notary,cpr,hrdept,legaldept,committee};
    
if ( !notary ) {
      delete paramString.notary;
}
if ( !cpr ) {
      delete paramString.cpr
}
if ( hrdept == -1 ) {
      delete paramString.hrdept
}
if ( legaldept == -1 ) {
      delete paramString.legaldept
}
if ( committee == -1 ) {
      delete paramString.committee
}
    
return this.personService.personsPaginated(paramString);
```

Create the const object, then delete the key/value pairs that are not needed.

Comment: Great one!! deleting was the key :D